# Python OpenCV2 SVM get scores instead of yes/no responses

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I want to train a RBF kernel SVM for a 2-class problem. At the moment the SVM predicts only 0 or 1, but I want it to return the distance to the decision boundary. How can I achieve this?

```
self.svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
self.svm.setKernel(cv2.ml.SVM_RBF)
self.svm.train(features, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels)
res = svm.predict(testdata, True)
```

My features are np.arrays with dtype=np.float32, my labels are np.arrays with dtype=np.int and values are 0 for class "no", 1 for class "yes"

The documentation says that svm.predict returns scores for the second parameter being True, but I only get results like this:

> (0.0, array([[ 0.],
>          [ 0.],
>          [ 0.],
>          ..., 
>          [ 0.],
>          [ 0.],
>          [ 0.]], dtype=float32))

Do I have to change the SVM type? If so, which should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the scikit-learn package to generate your svm.

To train:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
clf=LinearSVC(C=1.0,  class_weight='balanced')
clf.fit(features, labels)
svm_w = clf.coef_[0]
svm_intercept = clf.intercept_[0]
```

To test:

```
response_list = list()
for ft in feature_list:
    val = (sum(p*q for p,q in zip(ft,svm_w)) + svm_intercept)[0]
    response_list.append(val)
```

This gives you the SVM response for the feature in terms of the distance from the hyperplane.

Comment: Thanks, sklearn svm seems to be much better than the one from openCV...

Comment: I've struggled with the opencv implementation of SVM too. skilearn is powerful.